# Questions on Azure DevOps Services and synching our On-Prem AD with Azure AD?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We're in the process of upgrading our TFS 2010 instance to Azure DevOps Services, using the recommended upgrade path of [**TFS 2010** => **TFS 2013.5** => **TFS 2019** => **Azure DevOps Services**] using the Data Migration Tool.

There is however a major concern within the organisation regarding the requirement to sync our On-Premises Active Directory with Azure Active Directory and this is mainly due to security reasons.

What I'd therefore like to understand are the following:

1. Having synchronized the On-Prem AD with Azure AD during the high-fidelity migration using the Data Migration Tool, how will future changes to our On-Prem AD be synched across to Azure AD and will it be an automated process?
2. Will Azure AD maintain persistent connectivity with our On-Prem Active Directory for as long as the organisation leverages Azure DevOps Services?
3. Is it possible to implement *Azure DevOps Services* using only an On-Prem AD for authentication and sign-on, in other words without the need to sync to Azure AD? And just for clarity, I'm not considering *Azure DevOps Server* on-prem as an option.

Comment: Did you research these questions before asking? What research have you done? What was unclear about it? What do you need help implementing?

Comment: By synchronizing your on-premises Active Directory with Azure Active Directory,  your company needs to employ the Azure Active Directory Connect tool (formerly known as the Directory Synchronization tool, Directory Sync tool, or the DirSync.exe tool): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity. More details about sync AD with AAD, you would need get help from AAD.